# What is the longest side length of the cuboid?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let there be a cuboid with side lengths $\lbrace{3,y,x: x,y\in\mathbb Z \rbrace}$ where $x$ and $y$ are values that give the cuboid the property that its surface area is equal to its volume. Find the longest side length of the cuboid.

Honestly on the surface this question looked innocent.

So, the equation setup would quite obviously be $$2xy+2(3x)+2(3y)=3xy$$ which rearranges to $$6x+6y=xy$$ $$6=\frac{xy}{x+y}$$

so here is what I found to be the issue; generally speaking, when you've got the product of two integers, or the sum of two integers, (etc.) you can say something about the two integers, i.e. both are even or odd, or one is even, one is odd, whereas here; since the quotient is required, almost nothing (to my knowledge) about the integers is known despite the fact that they cannot be negative or equal to $0$.

For me this yelled out trial and error, but I don't quite want to succumb to those means, is there anything anyone can point out about this equation that might help me out?

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form $$y=6+\frac{36}{x-6}$$ can you finish?

Comment: Not quite. I know that ideally you want to eliminate one of the variables, but I can't quite see how to do that from the equation.

Comment: not that n$$36=2^2\cdot 3^2$$ thus $x-6=2,..$

Comment: It's probably easier to write it as (x-6)(y-6)=36